# Create Predicate Function like PrimeQ :: fibonacciQ, pythgoreanQ

Tags: function-construction, number-theory

Yes, just define the function. i.e. Use the Fibonacci numbers. What are good practices to perform it? (Vague, let's get specific.)

1. Create list of Fib.s 0, to 1,000,000.
2. Make function _Integer parameter, name fibonacciQ.
3. Error trap with message if < 0, or > million.

Is that how, to do it? My real GOAL is **any {x,y,z}** of Pythagorean Triples (not {3,4,5}, or {3,10}, or {3,4,4,5} eg.), only one value tested per call, create a predicate function pythagoreanQ[ ] for them. Likely, load table from disk, when needed in a notebook. Is that my only practical alternative, unless computing pythags 3 .. 1,000,000 directly every time?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: `fibQ = TrueQ[# == Fibonacci@Round[Log[GoldenRatio, Sqrt[5] #]]] &`? `pythagQ = TrueQ[#1^2 + #2^2 == #3^2] &` or `pythagQ = TrueQ[{1, 1, 1} . #^2 == 0] &`?

Comment: "not {3,4,5}, or {3,10}, or {3,4,4,5}" -- does that mean that `pythagoreanQ[{3,4,5}]` should return `False`? "Select[ {3,13, 100, 17} returns {True, True, True, True}" seems to make no sense since `{3,13,100,17}` is not a triple at all. Also `Select[]` is a built-in function that does not return a list of `True` unless the input contained `True`. Do you mean `pQ[n]` should return `True` if `n` is a member of any Pythagorean triple?

Comment: Last part yes, "pQ[n] should return `True` if `n` is a member of any Pythagorean triple? `pQ[x,y,z]` is an invalid form, just as `pQ[x,z]` would be. ** A simple `Select[ data, pQ[ #] &]` is how  it will be called.

Comment: You should note that if $n$ is an integer greater than $2$, there always exist positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $x=n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PythagoreanQ[{x_Integer, y_Integer, z_Integer}] := 
  With[{forbiddenQ = (# < 0) &},
   If[AnyTrue[{x, y, z}, forbiddenQ], 
    Return@Failure[
      "PythagoreanQ::negativeInput", {"MessageTemplate" -> 
        "One or more supplied integers is negative.", 
       "MessageParameters" -> {}}]];
   2*Max[{x, y, z}]^2 == Plus @@ (#^2 &) /@ {x, y, z}
  ];
```